# VB.NET - Auto-Updating applications while its open?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, cmd

I have code set to execute at Runtime using `Form1_Load` the code is a simple Assembly Check to see if the Version is lower then one saved on a Server gotten through Webclient. From there if its lower it downloads the latest EXE and uses CMD to rename it and replace it with the old .exe (Somehow it works while the application is open)

The issues:

- It makes False Anti-Virus detections thinking its trying to Infect Other apps (Trojan Dropper Variant)
- It's not Effective in some cases (Example: The user downloads the app for the first time and renames it to something other then the Default EXE name, Then boom it wont work efficiently)
- CMD may not even work on some machines like School PC's e.t.c
- It's just in general not a good idea to use CMD.

What I don't want to do as a solution:

- Use a second .exe with its only purpose is of updating the application;
- CMD Duh
- Atleast try not to use Nuget Packages/external references from .dll's
- Not be code that only updates when the user presses Yes/OK on a MessageBox e.t.c

So what can I do to resolve this issue of having to use CMD?

My Current Code:

```
#Region "Update Checker"

#Region "Test Internet Connection"

    'Ping Google to see if the user has Internet Connected;
    Private Function TestInternetConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim ping As New Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()
            ping.Send("google.com")
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Check for an Update"

    Private Sub CheckForUpdate()

        'If the user is Connected to the Internet;
        If TestInternetConnection() Then

            Try

                'Using WebClient, get the Newest File Version;
                Using wc As New WebClient

                    'Latest Version;
                    Dim LatestVersion As String = wc.DownloadString("http://proxyfuel.xyz/version.txt")

                    'If the Latest Version is Newer then the Current Version;
                    If LatestVersion > Application.ProductVersion Then

                        'Download the Latest Version of the EXE file;
                        wc.DownloadFile("{Application EXE Direct Link}", Application.StartupPath & "\update.exe")

                        'Execute the CMD Batch File to replace the old EXE file with the Newest EXE file;
                        Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", String.Format("/k {0} & {1} & {2} & {3}", "ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL", "del ""ProxyFuel.exe""", "REN ""update.exe"" ""ProxyFuel.exe""", "start """" ""ProxyFuel.exe""")).WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)

                        'Close the Application;
                        Application.Exit()

                    Else

                        'Start Loading the Main Form;
                        My.Settings.updatechecked = True

                    End If

                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception

                'Updating had an Unexpected Error;
                MessageBox.Show(ex, "Update Error!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

            End Try

        Else

            'No Internet Connection - Couldnt connect to the Data Server;
            MessageBox.Show("Internet Connection Required!", "Error")

        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

#End Region
```

Comment: `(Somehow it works while the application is open)` impossible. Maybe it is failing silently.

Comment: @Plutonix Thats a possibility but since it doesnt actually load show the form and closes the application roughly the same time as it opens maybe maybe not

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situations where I need to update an app that is currently running. I created an intermediate app to do the renaming (updating), this way the main app can be renamed successfully, otherwise when the main app is still running the file will be locked for most file operations.

1. Say, my main app is [main] and updater is [updater]
2. [main] will check if there's newer version
3. [main] will download with different name [main-new]
4. [main] will run [updater] and close/exit itself
5. [updater] will rename from [main-new] to [main]
6. [updater] upon success, run [main] and close/exit itself

*note:
you don't have to use CMD to rename file, use:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Test.txt", "SecondTest.txt")
```

*from [Rename File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w05844e.aspx)

Hope this help.

Comment: Oh wow thats quite handy - But its there a way to somehow do this with one .exe like maybe combine/store/compress the 2 .exe's into one and just load the other then needed?

Comment: You might wanna use DLL and load unload as needed. I think you need to design your .EXE as launcher and as much possible compartment your app into DLL modules, if any revision needed you only update the DLL.

Comment: Good idea but I think for my Lightweight app its just too much work doing that :/

Comment: Ok im trying this in a new angle - Im in the Application Events file and I added my UpdateChecker code as a Function with some of it slightly changed - I then in the Startup Event check if the function says theres an update and will download the new exe to wherever the app was opened from. And all works good but the issue is how can I stop the app from loading if theres an update? I tried just doing Form1_Load with Hide() and Close() but for some reason my app stays open even when I do that :/

Comment: It seems to be due to my Closing Animation - Working on it.